# Recieving Leap frames simulatenously in javascript and java

Tags: java, javascript, leap-motion

I'm using java with Robot to move mouse on the machine, & I wanted to receive gestures in javascript.

Individually, both trackings are working fine, but as soon as I focus on my LeapSDK's javascript example page, Java tracking goes away & mouse movement stops.

One dirty solution would be to track gestures in java & run a websocket server to transfer data to the javascript code.

But I was wondering if this is achievable without using any server. Background policy is on and configured in Java's code. Also, on one random page reload attempt, both mouse was controllable through leap and frame data was visible in js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have noticed, the background frames policy only applies to non-Leap-enabled apps. When another Leap-enabled app is in the foreground, you still don't get frames.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But isn't there any way for a developer to control this. Especially when working with js apps which involve mouse control, it is painful to track and trigger events. In terms of security, I don't think there should be any concern for two apps by a same developer running in tandem, serving different purposes individually(java&js in this case).

Comment: If you can recompile the Java library using SWIG (and the Leap.i file) you could add an item to the Policy enum with the value of (1 << 15) -- or so I'm told; I haven't tried it myself. That policy, which isn't part of the public API lets the background app get frames all the time. And the restriction isn't due to security, it is to prevent a bad user experience when two apps are moving the cursor or drawing things to the screen at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try recompiling. For now, I've used a websocket connection to transfer data to js.

Answer (score 0):

Going along with Charles Ward's answer, the following worked for me:
`com.leapmotion.leap.LeapJNI.Controller_setPolicy(Controller.getCPtr(controller), controller, 1 << 15);`